# WARNING: The 'Forge Design Automation v2' API is deprecated in favor of the 'Forge Design Automation v3' API npm package (aka ), please upgrade

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am following the tutorial for the Autodesk Forge - View your models. When I run debugging and got the following errors: [WARNING: The 'Forge Design Automation v2' API is deprecated in favor of the 'Forge Design Automation v3' API npm package (aka ), please upgrade.] How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Design Automation API v2 is deprecated - that means the API and service are still working but you should migrate to the v3 API as soon as possible, and if you are new to Design Automation, you should avoid using v2 and go straight to v3. You can install the v3 API using

```
npm install autodesk.forge.designautomation --save
```

NPM registry - https://www.npmjs.com/package/autodesk.forge.designautomation

You cannot remove the deprecation message, it will disappear in a few months when the v2 API will be removed.

I also have an example using this new package located [here](https://github.com/cyrillef/autodesk.forge.designautomation-sample), this example follows the steps described on the [learnforge tutorial](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/modifymodels).